# I have problem in next signIn function I got undefine from signIn response

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth

**signIn function**

This is my signIn function i want return value here from the provider but i got undefine.
i stuck here and i need help if any one know please reply to this post

```
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react'

const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) => {

    console.log({values});

    const signInData = await signIn('credentials',{
      email: values?.email,
      password: values?.password
    })
     
    console.log({signInData})
    if(signInData?.error){
      console.log(signInData?.error)
    } else if(!signInData ){
      
    } else {
      router.push('/admin')
    }
  };
```

**Auth provider component**

And this is my auth provider i dont get return i just get undefine from all cases i am using nextJs 13 version with app pages structure.

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { db } from "./db";
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter'
import { compare } from "bcrypt";

export  const authOtions: NextAuthOptions = {
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt'
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: '/sign-in'
    },
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
          name: "Credentials",
          credentials: {
            email: { label: "Email", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
            password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
          },
          async authorize(credentials) {
            if(!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password){
                return null
            }
            const exsitingUser = await db.user.findUnique({
                where: { email: credentials?.email}
            });

            if(!exsitingUser) return null;
            
            const passwordMatch = await compare(credentials?.password, exsitingUser.password)
            
            console.log({credentials, exsitingUser, passwordMatch})
            
            if(passwordMatch) return null

            return {
                id: `${ exsitingUser?.id || 0}` ,
                username: exsitingUser.username || 'test',
                email: exsitingUser.email || 'test@'
            }
            
          }
        })
      ],
}
```